# How to find the position of a pattern in a string using PHP?

Tags: php

I'm a newbie to php. is there any function that can match a pattern in a given string and and return the index of the beginning of the pattern within that string?
eg: if `$pattern = '/abcd/'`, `$string = 'weruhfabcdwuir'` then the function should return 6 since 6 is starting index of `'abcd'` in `$string`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to match a regexp pattern (not a straight string), `strpos()` won't help you. Instead, use [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) (if you only want to match on the first occurrence) or [`preg_match_all()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) (if you want to match all occurrences) and the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag:

```
$pattern = '/abcd/';
$string = 'weruhfabcdwuir';

preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

// $matches[0][0][1] == 6, see PHP.net for structure of $matches
print_r($matches);
```

Example with more than one match using `preg_match_all()`:

```
$pattern = '/abcd/';
$string = 'weruhfabcdwuirweruhfabcdwuir';

preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

// $matches[0][0][1] == 6
// $matches[0][1][1] == 20
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `strpos()` for this.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php